# pandas agg for datetime returns incorrect result

Tags: python, pandas

groupby.agg() return incorrect result(or at lease very misleading) for datatime series.   Here is the code snippet (Pandas version : 0.19):

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':pd.to_datetime("2017-01-01")})

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   A          B
0  1 2017-01-01
1  2 2017-01-01
2  3 2017-01-01
3  4 2017-01-01

In [6]: df.groupby("A")['B'].agg(lambda s: s.nunique())
```

Since there is only one value, I would expect the return would be simply 1, however, the actually result is very strange:

```
Out[6]: 
A
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
Name: B, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`nunique` itself works as expected, so the problem seems to be in `agg`

```
In [7]: df['B'].nunique()
Out[7]: 1
```

Comment: pandas is preserving the type of column B which is a pandas `Timestamp` based on numpy's 64 bit datetime object. Any integer is the number of nanoseconds since the epoch - Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: what's the rationale for preserving Timestamp type? Why not just leave it to the function to decide what to return?

Comment: Not sure. It might be worth creating an issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby("A")['B'].agg('nunique')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as a "typo" to me. "A" and "B" should be the other way round.

```
df.groupby("B")['A'].agg(lambda s: s.nunique())
```